# APPLE APP SITE ASSOCIATION (AASA) Troubleshooting - iOS - Wordpress hosted site

Tags: ios, wordpress, associated-domains, aasa, apple-app-site-association

I'm trying to set up AASA for my app and am testing on a Wordpress hosted site (https://toycollectorapp.com)

I have uploaded the AASA file to the .well-known directory and added an .htaccess file so that Wordpress will apply the mime/JSON type to the file. The page validates using the Branch IO validator - https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/

I've added the entitlements in Xcode (applinks:toycollectorapp.com) and added the associated domain capability at developer.apple.com for

Even with all that, when I visit the site with the application installed I am not prompted to open the app... the site and application don't seem to be talking with each other... Any advice on what I could troubleshoot? Is it an issue with Wordpress?

It seems like this should be easy, so I'm not sure what I am missing... any advice would be appreciated. Zack

Answer (score 1):

I went back in and added the old format with the apps:[] and appID and now it works! Even though the Apple WWDC 2020 says those items are no longer necessary, I guess they are! This formatting worked:

```js
{
  "applinks":{
    "apps":[],
    "details":[
      {
        "appID":"xxxxxxxx.com.threebrothersapps.hobbydbvision",
        "paths":[
          "/*"
        ],
        "appID":"xxxxxxxx.com.threebrothersapps.hobbydbvision",
        "paths":[
          "/*"
        ],
        "appIDs":[
          "xxxxxxx.com.threebrothersapps.hobbydbvision",
          "xxxxxxx.com.threebrothersapps.hobbydbvision"
        ],
        "components":[
          {
            "/":"/*"
          },
          {
            "/":"/support/home/*"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Apple's validation tool: https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool. I did a quick search for `toycollectorapp.com` and the validator could not reach your AASA.

Beyond that, you should also make sure the provisioning profile you're using contains the entitlement you added. If you're managing code signing manually, you need to re-generate a new one after you add a new capability to your App ID.

Comment: I’ve read that Apple tool isn’t always accurate, so I wasn’t sure what to make of that error. It isn’t very useful or clear. And when I upload my app to the App Store it says the associated domain entitlements are included... is there another way to check? Did the AASA format look okay?

Comment: The AASA format looks ok. Did you upload your AASA file very recently? Apparently iOS 14 doesn't go to your website directly. You can also try the old way of going directly to your web service with a tweaked entitlement value (<service>:<fully qualified domain>?mode=<alternate mode>) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/supporting_associated_domains

Comment: Uploaded it yesterday. Edited it this morning though to include the older iOS format as well (with apps: []). I thought the alternate mode was for private domains... this is public facing...